# What is required library needed for installing xmlreader in php:7.2-fpm-alpine custom docker image?

Tags: php, xml, docker

For this composer [package](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) I need the xmlreader into my custom docker php image:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --update libzip-dev libmcrypt-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libxml2-dev icu-dev postgresql-dev curl-dev libmemcached-dev &&\
    apk add --update --virtual build-dependencies build-base gcc wget autoconf &&\   
    docker-php-ext-install gd && \
    docker-php-ext-install zip &&\
    docker-php-ext-install dom xml xmlwriter xmlreader &&\
    apk del build-dependencies &&\
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

But when I build it I get the following error:

```
/usr/src/php/ext/xmlreader/php_xmlreader.c:32:10: fatal error: ext/dom/dom_ce.h: No such file or directory
 #include "ext/dom/dom_ce.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:194: php_xmlreader.lo] Error 1
Removing intermediate container 0b3f031b2479
```

So I assume that I am missing some library but which one I am missing?

The obviously `dom` extention that is also required Is installed via `docker-php-ext-install` and I also the reqwuired `libxml2-dev` is installed as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The XMLWriter extension was initially a PECL extension for PHP 5. It
>   was later added to the PHP source (bundled) as of PHP 5.1.2. This
>   extension is enabled by default.
>
> The XMLReader extension was initially a PECL extension for PHP 5. It
>   was later moved to the PHP source (bundled) as of PHP 5.1.0, and later
>   enabled by default as of PHP 5.1.2.

You need remove `dom, xmlwriter and xmlreader`

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --update libzip-dev libmcrypt-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libxml2-dev icu-dev postgresql-dev curl-dev libmemcached-dev &&\
    apk add --update --virtual build-dependencies build-base gcc wget autoconf && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd && \
    docker-php-ext-install zip &&\
    docker-php-ext-install xml &&\
    apk del build-dependencies &&\
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

I checked, work fine. Hope help you.